# Функция обратной транслитерации (АНГЛ->РУССК) PHP

Tags: php, функции

Есть такие уже? Пробовал переписать наоборот с помощью strtr(); - почему то не вышло.
Обычная транслитерация работает - а наоборот нет.

Comment: Для обратной транслитерации нужно всего одну функцию дописать. В этой статье описано: [Прямая и обратная транслитерация на PHP](http://bydlokoder.ru/index.php?p=article9)

Answer (score 3):

```
$trans = array(
    "а"=>"a",  "б"=>"b",  "в"=>"v",  "г"=>"g",
    "д"=>"d",  "е"=>"e",  "ё"=>"yo", "ж"=>"j",
    "з"=>"z",  "и"=>"i",  "й"=>"i",  "к"=>"k",
    "л"=>"l",  "м"=>"m",  "н"=>"n",  "о"=>"o",
    "п"=>"p",  "р"=>"r",  "с"=>"s",  "т"=>"t",
    "у"=>"y",  "ф"=>"f",  "х"=>"h",  "ц"=>"c",
    "ч"=>"ch", "ш"=>"sh", "щ"=>"sh", "ы"=>"i",
    "э"=>"e",  "ю"=>"u",  "я"=>"ya",

    "А"=>"A",  "Б"=>"B",  "В"=>"V",  "Г"=>"G",
    "Д"=>"D",  "Е"=>"E",  "Ё"=>"Yo", "Ж"=>"J",
    "З"=>"Z",  "И"=>"I",  "Й"=>"I",  "К"=>"K",
    "Л"=>"L",  "М"=>"M",  "Н"=>"N",  "О"=>"O",
    "П"=>"P",  "Р"=>"R",  "С"=>"S",  "Т"=>"T",
    "У"=>"Y",  "Ф"=>"F",  "Х"=>"H",  "Ц"=>"C",
    "Ч"=>"Ch", "Ш"=>"Sh", "Щ"=>"Sh", "Ы"=>"I",
    "Э"=>"E",  "Ю"=>"U",  "Я"=>"Ya",

    "ь"=>"",   "Ь"=>"",   "ъ"=>"",   "Ъ"=>""
);

echo strtr("Слово", $trans);
```

Вот примерно так. А если наоборот, то создай еще одну переменную, где поменяй местами английские и русские.

Comment: Это обычная транслитерация, из русских символов в англ. А мне нужно наоборот, менял местами - не работает.

Comment: Ваш код где Вы меняли местами покажите)

Comment: Интересно. [Здесь есть пример](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strtr.php)

А у Вас он работает ?

Comment: Не работает, если этот массив просто отразить: возвращается пустая строка. Это от того что в отраженном массиве есть элемент ['' => 'Ъ']. Нужно нормально составить массив, чтобы соответствия твердому и мягкому знакам были не пустые строки, а строки '' и ' (инфа из Punto Ыцшесрук`а). Важно не попутать местами: чтоб сначала заменялись твердые знаки, а только потом — мягкие.

Кроме того, можно сделать так:
    
    $trans = array_flip($trans);
    unset($trans['']);

Answer (score 0):

```
function translit($str) {
    $rus = array('А', 'Б', 'В', 'Г', 'Д', 'Е', 'Ё', 'Ж', 'З', 'И', 'Й', 'К', 'Л', 'М', 'Н', 'О', 'П', 'Р', 'С', 'Т', 'У', 'Ф', 'Х', 'Ц', 'Ч', 'Ш', 'Щ', 'Ъ', 'Ы', 'Ь', 'Э', 'Ю', 'Я', 'а', 'б', 'в', 'г', 'д', 'е', 'ё', 'ж', 'з', 'и', 'й', 'к', 'л', 'м', 'н', 'о', 'п', 'р', 'с', 'т', 'у', 'ф', 'х', 'ц', 'ч', 'ш', 'щ', 'ъ', 'ы', 'ь', 'э', 'ю', 'я');
    $lat = array('A', 'B', 'V', 'G', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'Gh', 'Z', 'I', 'Y', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'F', 'H', 'C', 'Ch', 'Sh', 'Sch', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'E', 'Yu', 'Ya', 'a', 'b', 'v', 'g', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'gh', 'z', 'i', 'y', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'f', 'h', 'c', 'ch', 'sh', 'sch', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'e', 'yu', 'ya');
    return str_replace($lat, $rus, $str);
}
echo translit("Переводит с latinki на russkiy!");
```